# Difference between defining multiple variable at a time and individually

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in Python and I'm trying to learn Python through self-learning. I was trying to build Fibonacci series using a `while` loop. Here is my code, which doesn't return the desired result. Could anyone explain the problem?

```
a = 0
b = 1

while b<100:
    print(b)
    a = b
    b = a + b
```

If we define `a, b` simultaneously like `a, b = b, a+b`, this works perfectly. Why is this happening? I don't understand because in both cases I am defining a and b the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because programming languages like Python, and many others, execute the statements you write in the order you write them.

This means that by the time you execute `b = a + b`, the value of `a` has already changed in the previous line.

An easy way to solve this would be using a third variable to store the results temporarily.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 1

while c < 100:
    print(c)
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are changing the value of `a` before evaluating `b`. In the Fibonacci series, you want the previous value of a and b. You can use `list` as above or can introduce another variable to store values.

```
while True:
    temp = a + b
    if temp >100:
        break
    print(temp)
    a = b
    b = temp
```

For reference, here is a simple implementation using `list`:

```
lst = [0, 1]
while True:
    temp = lst[-1]+lst[-2]
    if temp>100:
        break
    lst.append(temp)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making one small mistake.

When you do `a = b`, you are changing the value of `a`. After this, when you do `b=a+b`, it is actually equivalent to `b = b+b` => `b=2b`.

To avoid this, use a temporary variable `temp` and storethe value of `a` in it. Then change the value of `a` using `a = b`. Then do, `a = a+b`.

Following is the code:

```
a=0
b=1

while b<100:
    print(b)

    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp+b
```

When you do `a, b = b, a+b`, the previous value of `a` is used for calculating the new `b`, we have don a similar thing above by storing the previous value of `a` in `temp`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and giving concept of temp variable

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it was helpful... Happy to help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Operator "comma" (`,`) in Python is used to create a tuple, and it is allowed to omit the parentheses that surround a tuple. The expression `a, b = b, a+b` is actually an assignment of one tuple to another:

```
(a, b) = (b, a + b)
```

This statement is executed by evaluating the tuple constructor on the right-hand side `(b, a + b)`. At this point, a new anonymous tuple (let's call it `c`) is created and the original values of `a` and `b` are not needed anymore. The tuple is then assigned elementwise to the tuple on the left-hand side. The new value of `a` becomes `c[0]` (that is, former `b`) and the new value of `b` becomes `c[1]` (that is, former `a+b`).

Comment: Thanks for the concept of defining a tuple using comma operator without parentheses